# Installation error:Pyproj

Tags: python, installation, pyproj

I try to install pyprog from cmd but I've the following error. Who can explain me to fix it?!

---

Collecting pyproj (from LatLon)
  Using cached pyproj-1.9.5.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    using bundled proj4..
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Andrea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 490, in _find_latest_available_vc_ver
        return self.find_available_vc_vers()[-1]
    IndexError: list index out of range

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Andrea\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pyproj\setup.py", line 72, in <module>
    objects = cc.compile(['nad2bin.c', 'src/pj_malloc.c'])
  File "C:\Users\Andrea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 345, in compile
    self.initialize()
  File "C:\Users\Andrea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 238, in initialize
    vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
  File "C:\Users\Andrea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 185, in msvc14_get_vc_env
    return EnvironmentInfo(plat_spec, vc_min_ver=14.0).return_env()
  File "C:\Users\Andrea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 844, in __init__
    self.si = SystemInfo(self.ri, vc_ver)
  File "C:\Users\Andrea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 486, in __init__
    self.vc_ver = vc_ver or self._find_latest_available_vc_ver()
  File "C:\Users\Andrea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 493, in _find_latest_available_vc_ver
    raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(err)
distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Andrea\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pyproj\

Answer (score 2):

For those on Macs that won't find helpful answers: try

```
    pip install git+https://github.com/jswhit/pyproj.git
```

this will probably ask you to install cython, so do just this

```
    pip install cython
```

This worked for me when nothing else worked. Thanks to @micahcochran on github.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is written in the last line:

```
Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
```

Did you tried download and install it?

Comment: @capituscapiti  Did you restart your computer after the installation?

Answer (score 1):

You can download pyproj binaries from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyproj) and install via: `pip install <filename>.whl`